# Cannot open Symmetric key by certificate as SQL user account

Tags: sql-server-2008, encryption, certificate

I create my key using a certificate like this:

`CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY some_Key_01

 WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256

 ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE myCert;

GO`

`GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON CERTIFICATE::myCert TO sqlUser;

GO`

`GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SYMMETRIC KEY::some_Key_01 TO sqlUser;

GO`

Then I try to open and us it like this:

`OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY some_Key_01

   DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE myCert;

GO

SELECT CONVERT(datetime, DecryptByKey(EncryptedField))

    AS 'DecryptedField'

    FROM MyTable;

GO`

But I get the message:
`Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 23

Cannot find the certificate 'myCert', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have the `control` permission on the certificate:

```
GRANT CONTROL ON CERTIFICATE::myCert TO sqlUser;
GO
```

And grant `references` permission on the key:

```
GRANT REFERENCES ON SYMMETRIC KEY::some_Key_01 TO sqlUser;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks. Mind if I ask, why References on the key? Why not just View Definitions?  Also, why Control, and not some subset of permissions on the certificate?